# Ignoring front missions, can this cause Popularity to drop?

Tags: atelier-rorona

If you ignore the quests from Etsy (don't accept them, but just ignore them) will your popularity drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "Ignore".

If you choose not to accept assignments then your Popularity wont decrease, however if accept a quest and ignore it, you'll fail it you'll get a 5% loss to your popularity. To fail a quest you need to let the deadline pass and after a few days Esty will cancel the quest.

I'm not sure if there is a popularity drop if you cancel a quest befpre it's failed however when your trying for endings with a popularity of <80 and you need it lowered you normally fail quests to forcefully drop it